# How to move sites and site collections to SharePoint 2016 web application

Tags: 2013, 2010, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, upgrade

I have SharePoint 2010 farm and from this, I want to move some sites and site collections to SharePoint 2016 web application. In sp 2016 farm there is web application created with sp 2016 content database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This move is called migration of sites. There are two ways to achieve this migration.

- Use the 3rd party tool which will directly migrate Sites/sitecollections from 2010 farm to SharePoint 2016. i.e. Sharegate, metalogix etc
- In 2nd method, you have to build a SharePoint 2013 farm in between SharePoint 2010 & sharePoint 2016. It is called database upgrade method.

  - create SharePoint 2013 farm.
  - Take the backup of SharePoint 2010 Databaste (which has all sites)
  - restore it in SharePoint 2013, fully upgrade to Sharepoint 2013 level
  - Now take the backup of database from SharePoint 2013 farm and Restore it SharePoint  2016
  - Upgrade the restore DB to SP 2016.
  - Now test the site collections

Comment: Hi in sp 2016 there is already web application I want to move site collection and sub sites under this web application ,for this can I use export site?

Comment: yes if the sites are already in SharePoint 2016 but not directly from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2016

Comment: those sites coll, subsites I am moving those do not exist in the sp2016 web application, and i don't want to create separate content db .

Comment: Problem is you cannot do direct migration. Once you have database in the SharePoint 2016...you can move the site collections in the existing DB using Move-spsite command, also export & import the sites in desired site collection

Comment: Other wise use the 3rd party to tool to avoid all this

Comment: Hi can I take backup of subsites in SharePoint 2010 and if i restore under SharePoint 2013 site collection it will work?, because when i do test-spcontentdatabase there are many missing features

Comment: You cannot take the backup rather you can export the subsute and import it.